# Why are some scientific numbers automatically rounded and others aren't?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Why is it that some numbers in scientific notation starting with 9.999999999999999 get rounded to 1 while others remain the same?

For example, in Google Chrome 20 the following happens.

`(9.999999999999999e+306).toString() === "9.999999999999999e+306" // true`

but

`(9.999999999999999e+303).toString() === "1e+304" // true`

Why is that? Is it a floating point issue?

However the strangest thing is that in Opera 11.64 `(1e23).toString() === "9.999999999999999e+22"`. I tried to report the 1e23 bug to Opera but no one replied.

Live Demo Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ekDK/3/

Source code of Demo

```
var console = console || {};
console.logToBody = function( str ){
    document.body.innerHTML += "" + str + "<br/>";
};      
var parts = ["9.999999999999999e", 310 ], tmp, tmp2;
while( parts[1]-- ){
    tmp = +(parts.join(''));
    if( /9.9{3,}e/.test( +tmp ) ){
        console.logToBody( tmp + " doesn't convert to " +  (+tmp).toPrecision(1) );
    }
    tmp2 = "1e"+parts[1];
    //Carakan Javascript Engine Math BUG:
    if( !/^1e*/.test( +tmp2 ) ){
        console.logToBody( tmp2 + " = " + (+tmp2) + " in the runtime environment.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because floating point numbers are actually [approximations of really big fractions](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: @minitech: how `9.999999999999999e+22` is different from `9.999999999999999e+306` ?

Comment: Does `float == string` convert the float to a string, or vice-versa?

Comment: @Mehrdad (number).toString() converts a number to a string. +("string") is the same as parseInt( "string", 10 ). Or it might be parseFloat("string")

Comment: @LarryBattle: Sorry I don't think that answered my question (or perhaps I'm not understanding it)... I was asking, if you use `==` on a float and a string, which is converted to which?

Comment: @Mehrdad -- What does the language spec say?

Comment: @HotLicks: I don't know, that's kind of why I'm asking...

Comment: @Mehrdad—Here you go: [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)

Comment: @larry battle— the expression `+x` is the same as `Number(x)`, per the specification for the [Unary + Operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6). Also helpful: [Number(value)](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.1.1)

Comment: @RobG: Ah, so it's converted to a number, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because floating point numbers are sometimes an approximation. Some numbers can't be represented by the floating point format, that is, a binary fraction, so they are  approximated http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

That is why you should never rely on floating point arithmetic without rounding it. A simple example is the following:

```
> 20.61 - .1
  20.509999999999998
```

Here's a great explanation of the floating point format http://www.randelshofer.ch/fhw/gri/float.html#chapterfloatingpointformat

**Ordinary Decimal**    178.125

**Scientific Decimal**  1.78125 E 102

**Scientific Binary**   1.0110010001 E 2111

Comment: It's more related to the fraction part, isn't it?

Comment: @zerkms -- Remember, the fraction part is in binary, and does not exactly translate to decimal in most cases.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I do, but I cannot get why exponent value changes the final result. `9.999999999999999e+306` vs `9.999999999999999e+303` --- why do we see the different behaviour in these 2 cases?

Comment: @zerkms -- Like I said, the fraction is in binary, not decimal.  The translation to decimal is approximate.